# Onclick list-item, display new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making a script that wil look like this:

[image]

This is the demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bvane/Lu4qw/4/)

The list in the first page is generated with javascript and it only
displays certain list-items. This works fine and it only displays list-items
where the category == category.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var data = [{
        "name": "Lichtbediening",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor lichtbediening",
        "img": "lichtbediening"
}, {
        "name": "Stopcontact",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor stopcontacten",
        "img": "stopcontacten"
}, {
        "category": "Lichtbediening",
        "name": "Enkele schakelaar",
        "info": "Een knop, een lamp",
        "img": "rolluikbediening"       
}, {
        "category": "Stopcontact",
        "name": "Enkel stopcontact",
        "info": "Twee knoppen, twee lampen",
        "img": "multimedia"     
}];

var output = '';
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    if(value.category != 'category') {
        return;
    } else {
        output += '<li><a href="#">'
        output += '<img src="img/' + value.img + '.jpg">'
        output += '<h2>' + value.name +'</h2>'
        output += '<p>' + value.info + '</p>'
        output += '</a></li>';
    }
});

$('#list_zoek_category').html(output).listview("refresh");

});
```

Now I want to display a new list when one list-item is clicked. First I want to 
generate a new list wich displays only the list-items where the category is the same as
the name of the item clicked. Example: When I click on the list-item with the name: lichtbediening" in the first list, the new list displays only list-items with the category: "lichtbediening".

What is the best way to do this? Is it better to re-generate the current list, or to go to a new page? But to keep in mind, when i click on an item in the second list, i want to go to a detail page. Also i want to create a backbutton to display the previous view.

Can anyone give me some advise, and maybe some help to start that direction?

Comment: As you only have 2 levels, have you considered a collapsible set where you expand an item to see the the second level and then when you click on the second level you could show the details in a popup or another page.

Comment: I have not. because it is possible one category can contain around 20 products. So the dropdown would get verry big and it would get unorganized